# What to expect from the Ferrari Museum in Maranello

Tags: italy, museums

I'm planning to visit the [Museo Ferrari](http://museo.ferrari.com/) in Maranello and I want to know if I would be able to sit in the racing cars (especially the F1-single-seaters).

If I want to avoid the confusion of the big tourist groups, on which weekday should I go?

Comment: For the first part of your question, do you mean you'd like other information besides those in the site? I see there is an english version of the museum site but sitting in the racing cars is not mentioned there.

Comment: I'd like information from somebody who has visited the museum

Comment: In this case I'll let other users provide the information you need. I can only suggest you to have a look here http://www.tripadvisor.it/Attraction_Review-g187802-d646051-Reviews-Galleria_Ferrari-Maranello_Province_of_Modena_Emilia_Romagna.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was there last September. No, you can't sit in the cars or even touch them (there are loads of staff members to make sure nobody touches them). The visit will take you no more than 40 minutes.

- When you enter the first thing you will see is the old racing cars and the office of Enzo Ferrari which includes a replica of him. Then when you go upstairs you can see the modern Ferraris and on the opposite side the old Ferraris, then you can move to the other area of the museum, where you can see a Ferrari Racing boat (I liked it), and after that a hall with several Ferrari F1 cars from the modern era along with pictures and helmets from Ferrari F1 drivers.

Also there's a small room where you can hear the different F1 engines.

I hope this information will help you.

P.S. The best part is that in front of the museum you can rent Ferraris and Lambos for a period of time, you can discuss the price and get yourself a treat.. I drove a Ferrari California and it was amazing (They let you floor the accelerator near the Ferrari Factory), but the drive experience is not related in any way with the museum.

Comment: thanks for the great answer though I'm naturally a little disappointed by its content

Comment: You're welcome, I agree with you.. they also have a Ferrari dashboard displayed and you can't touch that either.. I would rather spend the money trying a real Ferrari :)